# Time and Date picker type='datetime-local'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have two text-field html elements to pick **start** and **end** date/time respectively. How to make **start** date/time less than  **end** date/time?

```js
<v-text-field
  id="setTime"
  outlined
  type="datetime-local"
  label="Start time"
  v-model="plan.start"
>
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: Please add some more code about how you are getting the start date and end dates

Comment: Could you explain what the phrase "start date/time less than end date/time" means? For example, maybe you need to disable dates directly in datetime-local input, or maybe you are building a form and you need to append validation to it, or ... something else?

Answer (score 0):

first, disable end date/time conditional if there is no start date/time it must be disabled.
after that when user select start date/time then on validation check if end date/time is lessThan start date/time return error,
also, you can disable days lessThan start day/time in end date/time field (read your date/time picker library document)

you can use yup for validation date-time or do it manually:

if your date/time is in epoch format it's like this

```
const schema = yup.object({
  fromDate: yup.number().required(),
  toDate: yup.number().moreThan(yup.ref("fromDate")).required(),
});
```

I hope it help you